# How can I concatenate every unique possibility in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two arrays within a single array:

```
var arrayOfArrays = [['apple', 'banana'], ['carrot', 'leek']];
```

I want to concatenate all options in the first array with all options in the second array. So I would have the following 4 results:

```
var result = ['applecarrot', 'appleleek', 'bananacarrot', 'bananaleek'];
```

The solution should work with any number of sub-arrays. So we could have an array of fruits, vegetables and flowers, each containing `n` number of items. Each result must also contain one word from each sub-array. So if there are 3 sub-arrays, all results will contain 3 words.

Example with 3 arrays:

```
var arrayOfArrays = [['apple', 'banana'], ['carrot', 'leek'], ['rose', 'lily'];
var result = ['applecarrotrose', 'applecarrotlily', 'appleleekrose', 'appleleeklily', 'bananacarrotrose', 'bananacarrotlily', 'bananaleekrose', 'bananaleeklily'];
```

I have come up with the following but it only seems to produce `['applecarrot', 'appleleek']`.

```
combination(arrayOfArrays, '');

var strings = [];

function combination(array, str) {
    var current = array.shift();

    if (array.length > 0) {
        $.each(current, function(i,v) {
            combination(array, str + v);
        });
    } else {
        $.each(current, function(i,v) {
            strings.push(str + v);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7025

Comment: Thank you, that solution is slightly different to what I want but I'll see if I can get it working. (It allows for `['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd'...]`, where I would just want combinations that contain 1 from each array. `['abc', 'bcd']`)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any built in way you going to have to make your own. Fist off there isn't any need to have an array within an array. Your only dealing with two options really (base array and one or more modifier arrays) So you could construct a function to iterate over them:

```js
function combiner(base, subject) {
  return base.reduce(function(memo, baseValue) {
    subject.forEach(function(subjectValue) {
      memo.push(baseValue + subjectValue);
    });
    return memo;
  }, []);
}

var arrayOfArrays = [['apple', 'banana'], ['carrot', 'leek']];
var result = combiner(arrayOfArrays[0], arrayOfArrays[1]);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result.join(', ');
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See below for my solution. I hope I've understood your requirements correctly. You can see the output on the JSFiddle page below. Works with any number of sub-arrays.

Working Preview (3 sub-arrays): https://jsfiddle.net/gc90hsr3/

Working Preview (4 sub-arrays): https://jsfiddle.net/gc90hsr3/3

```js
function combine(arrays) {
    var first = arrays[0];
    var others = arrays.slice(0);
    others.splice(0, 1);
    
    var result = [];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < others.length; j++) {
            for(var k = 0; k < others[j].length; k++) {
                var str = first[i] + others[j][k];
                result.push(str);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
    
};


var arrayOfArrays = [['apple', 'banana'], ['carrot', 'leek'], ['orange', 'pineapple']];
var combined = combine(arrayOfArrays);

document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = combined;
```

```html
<p><strong>Input: </strong><span id="input"></span></p>
<p><strong>Output: </strong><span id="output"></span></p>
```

Comment: At first, I had that, but then, I though he wanted the input to be `['applecarrotorange', 'applecarrotpineapple', ...]`. I then realized that I had to work and conceded.

Comment: Actually, yours doesn't work with more than 3 arrays, but worry not, you can take my code : https://jsfiddle.net/bew9c6xj/1/.

Comment: You need more than three? Thought the original question was only two. Also doesn't that cascading pyramid of for-loop-doom get a but unwieldy to read? If you wrapped the logic into some kind of monad then a fluent syntax could make some sense of things.

Comment: Mine does work with more than 3 arrays. Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/gc90hsr3/3/

Comment: @ChrisMendes I'm sorry, i totally missed that part : *"So if there are 3 sub-arrays, all results will contain 3 words."* I guess he only want every possibility that use 1 element of each arrays. But i think my first comment still apply.

Comment: @Sukima Yes, the original question has 2 arrays, but he say it can should work for 3 arrays, and we assume it can work for `n` arrays. And for the pyramid of loop, I just did not create the recursive function when I realized I wasn't answering his question.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but the output for three arrays should be `applecarrotorange, applecarrotpineapple, appleleekorange, appleleekpineapple...`. ...then the same with banana at the start. I will re-write my question as I've not been very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Sukima wrote an excellent answer but it only works for 2 sub-arrays. You can use his `combiner` as a helper to achieve your goal:

```js
    function combiner(base, subject) {
      return base.reduce(function(memo, baseValue) {
        subject.forEach(function(subjectValue) {
          memo.push(baseValue + subjectValue);
        });
        return memo;
      }, []);
    }

    function combine(array){
      var first = array[0];
      var others = array.slice(1);
      if (others.length == 1) return combiner(array[0],others[0]);
      return combiner(array[0],combine(others));
    }

    var arrayOfArrays = [['apple', 'banana'], ['carrot', 'leek'], ['orange', 'pineapple']];
    var combined = combine(arrayOfArrays);
    
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = combined;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below for a working solution, if I've understood your requirements on my second attempt. This solution will work with any number of sub-arrays and any number of elements inside each sub-array.

Essentially, the key is for each sub-array to have it's own independent pointer, that is either incremented to point to the next string value, or reset back to 0 for all values to be grabbed again on the next cycle, but with a string from a preceding sub-array as the base.

Hope this helps, and hopefully I've finally correctly understood what you want :)

*Note: The hyphens are of course easily removable.*

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L1vohz2e/

```js
function combine(arrays) {
  var first = arrays[0];
  var source = arrays.slice(0); // Source = sub-arrays after first
  source.splice(0, 1);

  var result = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) { // Every first sub-array element
    
    var pointers = {}; // Sub-array element pointers
    for(var p = 0; p < source.length; p++) {
      pointers[p] = 0;
    };
    var parentPointer = source.length-1; // Pointer for parent array, pointing to a sub-array (starting with last)

    while(parentPointer > -1) {
      var str = '';
      var j;
      for(j = 0; j < source.length; j++) { // Every sub-array
        str = str + '-' + source[j][pointers[j]]; // Grab strings that pointers are currently pointing at
      }
      result.push(first[i] + str); // Add line item to results array
      str = '';

      var k;
      var done = true;
      
      for(k = source.length-1; k > -1; k--) { // Every sub-array pointer starting at the end (going backwards)
        if(pointers[k] < source[k].length-1) { // If pointer not EOF (end of file), point to the next element
          pointers[k]++;
          parentPointer = k; // This pointer (sub-array) is the closest to the right that has strings not yet grabbed
          done = false; // We're not done, more strings to grab
          break;
        }
      }
      if(done) break; // Or, every pointer is pointing to the end of its sub-array (EOF), then we've grabbed everything
      for(var l = parentPointer+1; l < source.length; l++) { // If not done, reset all pointers in front of parentPointer set above
        pointers[l] = 0;
      }
    }

  }

  return result;
};



var arrayOfArrays = [['apple', 'banana'], ['carrot', 'leek'], ['orange', 'pineapple'], ['kiwi', 'grape']];
var combined = combine(arrayOfArrays);

var output = '';
for(var c in combined) {
  output = output + '<li>' + combined[c] + '</li>';
}

document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p><strong>Input: </strong><span id="input"></span></p>
<p><strong>Output: </strong></p>
<ul id="output"></ul>
```